# When Completed event is fired after execute Socket.SendAsync?

Tags: c#

When Completed event is fired after execute Socket.SendAsync?

I want to know when Completed event is fired after execute Socket.SendAsync.

When Socket.SendAsync process has been done at local endpoint? 
Or When Socket.SendAsync process has been done and receive Ack from the remote endpoint?

I'm investigating why Complete event does not infrequently occur after execute Socket.SendAsync.

By the way, I take into consideration the case Socket.SendAsync has been completed synchronously.

```
bool willRaiseEvent = listenSocket.AcceptAsync(acceptEventArg);
if (!willRaiseEvent){
    ...
}
```